# Docker problem with Springboot Batch-REST-app based on two DBs

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-batch

I am new to Docker and I containerized a Springboot REST-application based on a single DB without problems. But when I tried to do a similar set of containers based on a application that manages two DBs I run into trouble. When I run the Docker Compose I got a single error saying that it can not find the DB socio_bank_db. See pls the listed error-block for more details.

```
sociobankdbpostgres | 2020-09-12 19:58:09.404 UTC [32] FATAL:  database "socio_bank_db" does not exist
sociobank          | 2020-09-12 19:58:09,472 ERROR [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
sociobank          | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "socio_bank_db" does not exist
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2618)
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:135)
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:250)
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
sociobank          |    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
sociobank          |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
sociobank          |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
sociobank          |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
sociobank          |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
sociobank          |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
sociobank          |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
sociobank          |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
```

Next find the Docker and Compose files together with the application properties:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8082
RUN mkdir -p /app/
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs/
COPY /target/sociobank-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=container", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]


version: "3"
services:
  sociobankdb:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: sociobankpostgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=socio_bank_db
# second DB***************************************** 
  sociobankmetadb:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: sociobankmetapostgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=socio_bank_batch_meta_data_db
# APP*****************************************
  springbootapp:
    image: sociobank:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: sociobank
    expose:
      - 8082
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - sociobankdb
      - sociobankmetadb
    links:
      - sociobankdb
      - sociobankmetadb
volumes:
  postgres-data:


#Backend validation messages
spring.messages.basename=error-messages
spring.messages.cache-seconds=-1
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8

spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

#app.datasource.batch.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/socio_bank_batch_meta_data_db
app.datasource.batch.url=jdbc:postgresql://sociobankmetadb:5432/socio_bank_batch_meta_data_db
app.datasource.batch.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
app.datasource.batch.username=postgres
app.datasource.batch.password=postgres
app.datasource.batch.schema=classpath:metadata.sql

#app.datasource.db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/socio_bank_db
app.datasource.db.url=jdbc:postgresql://sociobankdb:5432/socio_bank_db
app.datasource.db.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
app.datasource.db.username=postgres
app.datasource.db.password=postgres
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
server.port=8082
```

Finally I list all classes concerning the configuration of the two DBs in Postres.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.artsgard.sociobank.repository", "com.artsgard.sociobank.config" },
                entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbEntityManagerFactory", 
                transactionManagerRef = "dbTransactionManager")
public class BatchDbRepoConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dbDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.db")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.db.hikari")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("dbDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    

    @Bean(name = "dbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dbDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .packages("com.artsgard.sociobank.model")
                    .persistenceUnit("db")
                    .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("dbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {       
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class BatchDbMetaDataRepoConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "batchDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.batch")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "batchDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.batch.hikari")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("batchDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}

public class JobRepositoryConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("transactionManager")
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("batchDataSource")
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType(DatabaseType.POSTGRES.getProductName());
        factoryBean.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(datasource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

The application can be found at github

[sociobank application](https://github.com/artsgard/sociobank)

And by the way outside of Docker (localhost) things work!

Answer (score 0):

You are using same port mapping in both postgres instances. Change them to use different port. Consequently change the port in the application also and things should work. Read about docker networks for more clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse! But what should I do:

Comment: app.datasource.db.url=jdbc:postgresql://sociobankdb:5432/socio_bank_db

Comment: app.datasource.batch.url=jdbc:postgresql://sociobankmetadb:5433/socio_bank_batch_meta_data_db

Comment: for instance. But it is not clear to me what the ports at the Compose file should be: the one of 5432 should map into ports ?:?

Comment: and the one of 4533 ports ?:?

Comment: But anyway on local, without docker, I never touched those ports they stayed on 5432 for both dbs and things worked, how come?

Comment: Locally you must have created different databases in the same application which listened on 5432.if that's the case you can do this here to. In docker file create 2 different databases and use only 1 instance in docker compose.

Comment: But that is precisely  what I did, right? See the springboot properties, where I created the two dbs, on the same port (listed up). Next see the Docker Compose´s services: sociobankdb and sociobankmetadb which refer each to those created DBs. So still do not get why I can not run it (btw I am looking into Docker network and believe that the  network_mode: bridge could be deleted at the Compose, right?) Here: [link](https://github.com/artsgard/socioregister) you can see it  working on one single DB.

Comment: BTW you are saying docker file but you mean docker compose, right?

Comment: having 2 databases in one database application is different than 2 databases in separate database applications. Locally you were running only 1 application and in docker-compose, you are trying to run 2 separate instances of Postgres which is the issue here. Either Remove 1 from docker-compose and then log in to the container after starting and create another database inside manually  Or you can run 2 separate instances running on separate ports and your application can connect to different databases separately.

Comment: If you don't want to manually create another database you can create a new docker image which can run create database command and use that in docker-compose. I hope it clears things up.

Comment: So I do not need to touch the config at the application (properties), right. It is all about the docker part?

Comment: I do not see what is wrong, sorry! I have two DB on two different ports 5432 and 5433! Mapping into sociobankdb and sociobankmetadb

Comment: If they are running in different ports then change in application properties to use them. Also exec into containers to verify they are working and respective dbs are created.